# a problem occurred in initializing MCI python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, python-playsound

I keep getting `error 277 : a problem occurred in initializing MCI.` when using `playsound` module. I basically just did this:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('what.mp3')
```

the `what.mp3` is generated using `gtts`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["A problem occurred in initializing MCI" playsound issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627901/a-problem-occurred-in-initializing-mci-playsound-issues)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is too late but try to install Klite Codec Pack and try again, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same issue using playsound by doing 2 steps:

1. I re-encoded the .mp3 with Audacity because the files that i downloaded from a webconverter was trashy.
   (still not working)
2. I added the True value at the end, like this:

   ```
    from playsound import playsound
    playsound('/path/to/a/sound/file/you/want/to/play.mp3, True')
   ```

Then it worked.
I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\\Users\\shubham sinha\\Desktop\\code\\01RitvizLiggiOfficialMusicVideoRingtone.mp3')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try using this test code to see if it works:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/path/to/a/sound/file/you/want/to/play.mp3')
```

If it doesn't install it again or try another version of python.

Comment: Hi I tried adding path but same error. I also tried going from 3.7.4 to 3.7.2 but same error. I also did pip uninstall playaudio then install again but same error =(.

Comment: Oh, then I son't really know what to do, sorry :(

Answer (score -1):

you should write like this:

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\\Users\\Talha Shafiq Chadhry\\Downloads\\Video')
```

Answer (score -1):

I used to get this error, Now solved...
Try this one

```
import playsound
playsound.playsound("D:\\Yalgaar.mp3")
```

Here Yalgaar is saved in my D drive