# Error python when use playsound + os path

Tags: python, python-playsound

i use this line for my game

```
playsound(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , 'asset', C1 + '.mp3'))
```

it's work well on linux but on windows i get output:

```
raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 275 for command:
        open "E:\test\asset\sound3.mp3" alias playsound_0.4871568054138944
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct
```

when i type full path

```
Error 277 for command:
        open "E:\JPssetound3.mp3" alias playsound_0.511238440569949
    A problem occurred in initializing MCI.
```

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the path instead?

Comment: Try converting to a wav file and check if that plays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["A problem occurred in initializing MCI" playsound issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627901/a-problem-occurred-in-initializing-mci-playsound-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists in a command prompt or File Explorer. The file should be present in the folder you are expecting.

Comment: Did you check if the file is NOT corrupted by playing the file using windows media player? Covert to WAV file to try? p.s. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627901/a-problem-occurred-in-initializing-mci-playsound-issues

Comment: I use k lite to open and it's well: os.system('start mpc-hc64.exe asset/"' + C1 + '.mp3')